# Installing Starlink on Old Sky Pole

Tags: electrical, mounting

I'm getting Starlink in a few days and I've bought the pipe adapter for it.

I've removed an old sky dish to reuse the mount for it, LoS from here is excellent according to the app.

[image: Old Sky Pole]

Firstly, should this be secure enough?

Secondly, what's going to be the best way to get the cable into the house? Drilling a 20mm hole through 80cm of whinstone doesn't sound fun... Reckon I can drop it into the loft somehow?

Comment: who installed that pipe on the right ?

Comment: Can you come through the window frame? It looks like wood so you might be able to drill a hole and pass the cable through a weather-sealed feed-through bushing mounted into the hole? Won't look... great, but'll work. Is there a reason you can't use the path for the old Sky cable?

Comment: @ruskes the PVC one?

Comment: @mjbraun, window frame isn't an option, the landlord would kill me, with the amount of holes for other cables going through the stone, he won't notice another, as for reusing the sky one, I don't think it will be big enough, there's quite a large connector on the end of the Starlink cable

Comment: Use the Sky cable hole as a pilot hole for your long 20 mm masonry bit (possibly involving tool hire) seems the best bet, at a guess. May be possible to go into the loft, but depends how things are built and what you can or can't do according to keeping the landlord happy. Does not look like you have good access at the edge of the roof. Very little exposed between the gutter and the wall

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Is there a specific type of drill I should be looking to hire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the new antenna is the same size, or smaller than, the old antenna, and the mount held the old antenna, it should hold the new antenna. If the new antenna is significantly bigger, (think wind loading more than mass) that becomes more of a judgement call on how over-engineered the old mount is.

I can't see anything that looks like a reasonable path into the loft in your pictures. A heavy duty masonry hammer drill and using the existing "Sky" cable hole as a pilot would be my best guess at doing this, with an appropriate long bit. Those will be "SDS, SDS-Plus or SDS-Max" in the current nomenclature for "serious" hammer drills, if you are going to hire one - with SDS-Max being the biggest and beefiest - though an alternative in hire equipment would be a suitable size core drill (diamond abrasive cutting a "ring" around the edge of the hole, not hammer-drilling) or just walk into (or call/email) your local tool hire shop and show them what you are up against, as I'm sure they are familiar with local construction and how best to get through it.

Comment: I did rent a drill... Lost the fight with the wall and very nearly snapped my wrist... The cable's gone in through the window and I've stuffed the gap with scarves... The dish is holding up nicely on the poll though